# JS file couldnt access laravel variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am passing an array from my controller.

Now, I put this code inside my Laravel 6.* Blade View,

```
<script>
    var app = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
</script>
```

This works just fine.

However, if I put the same piece of line (or any of the following lines) inside my custom app.js file, this doesn't work.

```
var app = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

var app = {!! json_encode($array->toArray()) !!};

var app = '<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>';
```

Each time I am getting an invalid syntax error.

I am not sure if this is a valid ques for StackOverflow, but I have already tried all other similar solutions and none of them is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have no access to write php code in js file or you can use `Ajax` to get php variable.

In your statement if you put your code in your blade file before including `app.js` file you will be able to get `app` variable in your js file.
Ex:

```
<script>
var app = @json($array)
</script>
<script src="path to your app js file"></script>
```

And now in your app js file if you print `app` variable you will see the result 
`console.log(app);` in your app.js file

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to move javascript to template and create route to it as:

```
Route::get('/app.js', function () {
    $result = view('app', ['array' => [1,2,3,5,8]]);
    return Response::make($result, 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
});
```

Then in resouces\views

```
<script>
    var app = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
</script>
```

Common way of doing this is to create end point that returns json only and then use e.g. fetch api or axios library on client side.

Something like this:

```
Route::get('/app', function () {
    return [1,2,3,5,8];
});

<script>
    fetch(endPointUrl("/app")).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    })
</script>
```

Where endPointUrl is just a helper function that creates full url.